# ¿Cómo escoger que propiedades mostrar en modo lista con OpenXava?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, openxava

Aquí está el código de mi entidad "Recapito":

```
@Entity @Getter @Setter
public class Recapito extends AceArcId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    private Contatto contatto; 

    @Column(length=254)
    private String email;

    @Column(length=254)
    private String telefono;

    @Column(length=254)
    private String sito;

    @Column(length=254)
    private String paginaSocial;

    @Column()
    private Date data;
}
```

Este pantallazo muestra como se visualiza por defecto:

[image: Propiedades de lista por defecto]

Me gustaría escoger que propiedades de "Contatto" se mostrarán para "Recapito", en lugar de sólo la propiedad "nome".

¿Cómo escoger que propiedades mostrar en modo lista?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la anotación @Tab para eso. @Tab te permite usar propiedades calificadas hasta un nivel infinito:

```
@Entity @Getter @Setter
@Tab(properties="contatto.nome, contatto.direzione.strada, telefono, email")
public class Recapito extends AceArcId implements Serializable {
```

Fíjate en contatto.nome y contatto.direzione.strada.

Además, tu usuario puede añadir cualquier propiedad que quiera, incluidas propiedades de Contatto en Recapito, usando las opciones de personalización de la lista.

Mira esta documentación para aprender más sobre @Tab:
https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/tab_es.html